# Creating 2 figures in Matlab in one area

Tags: matrix, plot, syntax-error, matlab-figure

From my syntax, I want to create 2 figure in one area, but I just get 1 figure

---

```
% Gaussian plume model for air pollution

%    using MATLAB analytical solutions                   

%

%---------------------stack1--------------------------------------------

v = 0.5;                    % velocity

lambda = 0;                 % decay rate

Q = 1;                      % emission rate(s)

u = 3;                      % wind speed

P = 1;                      % Ambient Pressure

D = 6;                      % inside diameter

V = 22.4;                   % volumetric flow rate of stack gas 

Ts = 400;                   % temperature of stack gas  

Ta = 283;                   % temperature of ambient air  

xstack = 0; ystack = 50;    % stack location(s)

xmin = 0.5; xmax = 3.5;     % x-axis interval

ymin = 0; ymax = 100;       % y-axis interval (used only for d>1))

h = 50;                     % physical stack height

z = 0;                      % height of observation (=0 for ground surface)



%----------------------------------execution-------------------------------

[x,y] = meshgrid (linspace(xmin,xmax,100),linspace(ymin,ymax,100));

c = zeros (size(x)); e = ones(size(x));



Dy = linspace(1,100,100); %  in meters

Dz = Dy'; %  in meters

[Dy,Dz] = meshgrid(Dz,Dy);



for i=1:100

for j=1:100



%...Pasquill-gifford for Dy



c = 24.167; d = 2.5334;%...Pasquill Stability Category is A

if x(i,j)<0.10; % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));


Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

end





c = 18.3330; d = 1.8096;%...Pasquill Stability Category is B

if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 12.5000; d = 1.0857;%...Pasquill Stability Category is C

if x(i,j) == 4; % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 8.3330; d = 0.72382;%...Pasquill Stability Category is D

if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 6.2500; d = 0.54287; %...Pasquill Stability Category is E

if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 4.1667; d = 0.36191; %...Pasquill Stability Category is F

if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

end





%...Pasquill-gifford for Dz



if x(i,j)<0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 122.8; b = 0.9447;%...stabilitas is A

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 





if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.100 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.150

a = 158.08; b = 1.0542;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.150 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.200

a= 170.22 ; b= 1.0932 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 




if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.200 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.250

a= 179.52 ; b= 1.1262 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.250 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.300

a= 217.41 ; b= 1.2644 ; 

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.300 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.400

a= 258.89 ; b= 1.4094 ; 

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.400 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.500

a= 346.75 ; b= 1.7283 ; 

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.500 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif x(i,j) >= 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end





if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 90.673; b = 0.93198;%...stabilitas is B

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.40

a = 98.483; b = 0.98332;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end

elseif x(i,j)>= 0.40

a = 109.400; b = 1.09710;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end





if x(i,j) == all % x in kilometers

a = 61.141; b = 0.91465;%...stabilitas is C

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end







if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

a = 34.459; b = 0.86974;%...stabilitas is D

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.81066;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.64403;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 33.504; b = 0.60486;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 36.650; b = 0.56589;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j)>= 30.00

a = 44.053; b =0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end







if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 24.260; b = 0.83660; %...stabilitas is E  

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 0.10 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 23.331; b = 0.81956;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.75660;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.63077;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 4.00

a = 22.534; b = 0.57154;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 4.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 24.703; b = 0.50527;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 20.00

a = 26.970; b = 0.46713;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 20.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 40.00

a = 35.420; b = 0.37615;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j) >=40.00

a = 44.053; b = 0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end





if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 15.209; b = 0.81558;%...stabilitas is F

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.70

a = 14.457; b = 0.78407;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 0.71 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.68465;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.63227;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 14.823; b = 0.54503;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 7.00

a = 16.187; b = 0.46490;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 7.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 15.00

a = 17.836; b = 0.41507;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 15.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 22.651; b = 0.32681;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 30.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 60.00

a = 27.074; b = 0.27436;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j)>= 60.00

a = 34.219; b = 0.21716;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;

end

end

end





end



end







for i = 1:size(Q,2)

    xx = x - xstack(i);

    yy = y - ystack(i); 

end



    deltah(i,j) = V.*D./u.*1.5 + 2.68.*(10^(-3)).*P.*(Ts-Ta).*D./Ts;

    H = h + deltah;



    c1 = c + Q(i).*e./(4.*pi.*xx.*sqrt(Dy.*Dz)).*exp(-v.*yy.*yy./(4.*Dy.*xx)).*... 

    (exp(-v.*(z-H(i)).*(z-H(i)).*e./(4.*Dz.*xx))+exp(-v.*(z+H(i)).*(z+H(i)).*e.
/(4.*Dz.*xx)))...

    .*exp(-lambda.*xx./v);


%--------------------------stack2---------------------------------------------

v = 0.5;                    % velocity

lambda = 0;                 % decay rate

Q = 1;                      % emission rate(s)

u = 3;                      % wind speed

P = 1;                      % Ambient Pressure

D = 6;                      % inside diameter

V = 22.4;                   % volumetric flow rate of stack gas 

Ts = 400;                   % temperature of stack gas  

Ta = 283;                   % temperature of ambient air  

xstack = 0; ystack = 35;    % stack location(s)

xmin = 0.5; xmax = 3.5;         % x-axis interval

ymin = 0; ymax = 100;        % y-axis interval (used only for d>1))

h = 50;                     % physical stack height

z = 0;                      % height of observation (=0 for ground surface)

gplot = 1;                  % plot option (=1 yes; =0 no)

gcont = 2;                  % contour plot option (=2 filled; =1 yes; =0 none) 

%----------------------------------execution-------------------------------

[x,y] = meshgrid (linspace(xmin,xmax,100),linspace(ymin,ymax,100));

c = zeros (size(x)); e = ones(size(x));



Dy = linspace(1,100,100); %  in meters

Dz = Dy'; %  in meters

[Dy,Dz] = meshgrid(Dz,Dy);



for i=1:100

for j=1:100



%...Pasquill-gifford for Dy



c = 24.167; d = 2.5334;%...Pasquill Stability Category is A

if x(i,j)<0.10; % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

end





c = 18.3330; d = 1.8096;%...Pasquill Stability Category is B

if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 12.5000; d = 1.0857;%...Pasquill Stability Category is C

if x(i,j) == 4; % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 8.3330; d = 0.72382;%...Pasquill Stability Category is D

if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 6.2500; d = 0.54287; %...Pasquill Stability Category is E

if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers 

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th)); 

end





c = 4.1667; d = 0.36191; %...Pasquill Stability Category is F

if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

th = 0.017453293.*(c - d.*log(x(i,j)));

Dy(i,j) = 465.11628.*x(i,j).*(tan(th));

end





%...Pasquill-gifford for Dz



if x(i,j)<0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 122.8; b = 0.9447;%...stabilitas is A

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 





if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.100 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.150

a = 158.08; b = 1.0542;


Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.150 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.200

a= 170.22 ; b= 1.0932 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.200 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.250

a= 179.52 ; b= 1.1262 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.250 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.300

a= 217.41 ; b= 1.2644 ; 

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.300 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.400

a= 258.89 ; b= 1.4094 ; 

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.400 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.500

a= 346.75 ; b= 1.7283 ; 

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.500 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif x(i,j) >= 3.110

a= 453.85 ; b= 2.1166 ;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end





if x(i,j)<0.20 % x in kilometers


a = 90.673; b = 0.93198;%...stabilitas is B

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz(i,j)=5000;

end

elseif 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.40

a = 98.483; b = 0.98332;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 



if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end

elseif x(i,j)>= 0.40

a = 109.400; b = 1.09710;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end







if x(i,j) == all % x in kilometers

a = 61.141; b = 0.91465;%...stabilitas is C

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  


if Dz(i,j)>5000

Dz = 5000;

end



if x(i,j)== 0.30 % x in kilometers

a = 34.459; b = 0.86974;%...stabilitas is D

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end

if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.81066;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 32.093; b = 0.64403;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 33.504; b = 0.60486;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 36.650; b = 0.56589;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j)>= 30.00

a = 44.053; b =0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end







if x(i,j) < 0.10 % x in kilometers

a = 24.260; b = 0.83660; %...stabilitas is E  

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 0.10 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 23.331; b = 0.81956;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  
end



if 0.31 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.75660;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 21.628; b = 0.63077;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 4.00

a = 22.534; b = 0.57154;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 4.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 10.00

a = 24.703; b = 0.50527;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 10.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 20.00

a = 26.970; b = 0.46713;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 20.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 40.00

a = 35.420; b = 0.37615;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j) >=40.00

a = 44.053; b = 0.51179;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end





if x(i,j) < 0.20 % x in kilometers

a = 15.209; b = 0.81558;%...stabilitas is F

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 0.21 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 0.70

a = 14.457; b = 0.78407;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end


if 0.71 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 1.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.68465;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 1.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 2.00

a = 13.953; b = 0.63227;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b; 

end



if 2.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 3.00

a = 14.823; b = 0.54503;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 3.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 7.00

a = 16.187; b = 0.46490;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 7.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 15.00

a = 17.836; b = 0.41507;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 15.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 30.00

a = 22.651; b = 0.32681;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if 30.01 <= x(i,j) && x(i,j) < 60.00

a = 27.074; b = 0.27436;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;  

end



if x(i,j)>= 60.00

a = 34.219; b = 0.21716;

Dz(i,j)= a.*x(i,j).^b;

end

end

end





end



end







for i = 1:size(Q,2)

    xx = x - xstack(i);

    yy = y - ystack(i); 

end



    deltah(i,j) = V.*D./u.*1.5 + 2.68.*(10^(-3)).*P.*(Ts-Ta).*D./Ts;

    H = h + deltah;



    c2 = c + Q(i).*e./(4.*pi.*xx.*sqrt(Dy.*Dz)).*exp(-v.*yy.*yy./(4.*Dy.*xx)).*... 

    (exp(-v.*(z-H(i)).*(z-H(i)).*e./(4.*Dz.*xx))+exp(-v.*(z+H(i)).*(z+H(i)).*e.
/(4.*Dz.*xx)))...

    .*exp(-lambda.*xx./v);

%----------------------------------output----------------------------------

if gplot

    for i = 10:10:100

        plot (c1(:,i)); hold on;

        plot (c2(:,i)); hold on;

    end

end

if gcont

    figure;

    if gcont > 1

        contourf (x,y,c1); colorbar;

        contourf (x,y,c2); colorbar;

    else

        contourf (x,y,c1); 

        contourf (x,y,c2);

    end

end

end
```

Comment: nobody is actually going to read such chunk of code. please remove the code and explain your problem with a related part of code.

Answer (score 0):

FYI poorly written question

figure;

if gcont > 1

```
subplot(2,1,1), contourf (x,y,c1); colorbar;

subplot(2,1,2), contourf (x,y,c2); colorbar;
```

else

```
subplot(2,1,1),contourf (x,y,c1); 

subplot(2,1,2), contourf (x,y,c2);
```

end